# Something wrong with google-play-store visibility algorithm or idea

Tags: android, search, app-store

based on this video, i change my app title, keywords etc...but still can't get the app in play store search list https://play.google.com/store/... how to be discoverable if you just published a new app, if it is not on the search results...even if i type in the exact title of APP: "Allrecipes Healthy Food Recipe" or "Recipes from FoodTwitter" notice keyword "FoodTwitter" is pretty unique! but results are showing only top 300 recipe/recipes sites, but not mine. So, the point is...how new starters must tell users that there is a new app, if google store does not list them at all?

Comment: The app marketing is up to yourself. There is no way to set the app to the top search results at google play.

Comment: i'm not looking for to be on top of the store's search results, but just on the list when i search my specific title.

Comment: Do you have other apps published? If so go to your organizations page, if you see the app there, well and good. If not you might want to consider the manifest settings and the email id you are signed in with. In-case you have restricted your app to small/large screens.

Comment: Byzantine, if you see the app with that direct link above there is not restrictions, but rather everyone/all devices allowed ... :(

Answer (score 0):

It takes a while untill you have enough downloads for google to shoot you higher up the list(if there is competision with the same/very similar app names) and if it is your first upload and there are no other with the same name, it takes a while untill the search connects that name with your app.

When I started out, my app was far down on the list, but a few weeks later it was at the top and I'm guessing because it got five stars by several people and got a load of downloads.

Google Play Store Visibility Algorythm works in mysterious ways so it is hard to give an exact answer without working at google with the play store, but it should still help you. Once your app is starting to generate downloads, the more it gets the higher it goes. It is a hard market because of the millions on millions of apps, so you just have to keep trying!